# Scrollable div jumps to the top after it gets largely populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A bit of info about the problem:

I am using Internet Explorer 7/8 (This cannot change)

The website is dynamically populated and gets very large, it is essentially a book with a table of contents and buttons that expand/collapse chapters.

There is no issue with expanding/collapsing chapters at first until there is a fairly one very large chapter. The entire book is stored in a scrollable div.

When the problem occurs, anything above the large chapter work completely fine, as well as the chapter in question. The bug starts happening on chapters under the large one. When you expand/collapse and the chapter location is in the bottom half of the div it will work like normal. But if the chapter location is in the top half of the div it bugs out (Based on when you are currently scrolled when you click) that it will do the expand/collapse but will then jump to the very top of the table of contents (it sets the scrollbar to the top).

I don't have any logic for it to scroll to the top when a chapter gets expanded/collapsed I only have logic to change an icon and an invisible div status.

Things I've tried:

Setting a delay after the chapter gets expanded/collapsed and then scrollTo the location of that chapter. - Does not work, the scrolling to the top happens after anyway.

Changing how I do the expand/collapse - Does not work, same error.

Checked/changed a little bit of the dynamically added content - Does not work, everything is valid html and should not be the issue.

Prayed - Does not work.

Here is the code that expands/collapses the chapters:

```
function() {
    $id = $(this).parent().prop("id");
    $id = parseInt($id.replace("_other", ""));
    document.getElementById($id + "_arrow").innerHTML = "<span style = 'display:inline;float:left;' class ='ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-state-default'></span>";
    if ($("#" + $id + "_content").css("display") == "none") {
        $("#" + $id + "_content").css("display", "block");
    } else {
        $("#" + $id + "_content").css("display", "none");
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you have an example page with the book content so that we can try to recreate the bug in order to debug it? It would be most helpful if you could give us a link to your project or a fiddle with the same info.  Switch out the content for lorem ipsum if you don't want to share that.

Comment: If the content is getting injected/loaded via ajax, there could be conflict caused by the actual information being loaded. If you take @wolffer-east 's advice and replace with "lorum ipsum" does the problem persist?

Comment: It also looks like you are adding a float:left, which could be bouncing it to the top depending on the display settings of the rest of the chapters.

Comment: I'm not sure how easy that will be given the size of the site but I can try and throw together something and see if I still get the error and send that your way. As for the float-left every chapter has that, it is for the icon that does the expanding/collapsing to be on the left side of the chapter title. Also, nothing is changing site-wise, the only thing that changes is the scroll bar gets sent to the top.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you loaded in the data to the div using ajax each time you expanded a section and in the same jquery function, emptied/cleared out the other divs.